# Visual studio saying that std has no member move(std::move) . Why is it giving an error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2019

Below is my code:
Main.cpp

```
 #include "Integer.h"
    int main() {
           //1st object made
           Integer i1(5);
           Integer i2(std::move(i1));
           return 0;
    }
```

I have Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Have you tried including `<utility>`?

Comment: I'm guessing that `Integer` does not actually manage any resources, so a `std::move` will be the same as a copy in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

you haven't included the std::move =) try `#include <utility>`